# In JQuery Extension Function, how do I access the instance options?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have an JQuery Extension with Functions, I am not sure how to access the instance's options:

```
    (function ($) {

    $.fn.MyExtension= function (methodOrOptions) {
        if (methods[methodOrOptions]) {
            return methods[methodOrOptions].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || !methodOrOptions) {
            // Default to "init"
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + methodOrOptions + ' does not exist on jQuery.MyExtension');
        }
    };

    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            var defaults = {
                testOption: "test"
            };
            options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function () {
                 // Code logic goes here
            }

        MyFunction: function () {
            var optionVal = options.testOption;
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

So this code throw an error when I call MyFunction because it does not know what "options" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it on the element's data object. http://jsfiddle.net/U7QT5/

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.MyExtension = function (methodOrOptions) {
        if (methods[methodOrOptions]) {
            return methods[methodOrOptions].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || !methodOrOptions) {
            // Default to "init"
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + methodOrOptions + ' does not exist on jQuery.MyExtension');
        }
    };

    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            var defaults = {
                testOption: "test"
            };
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.data("MyExtension",$.extend(defaults, options));
                // Code logic goes here
            });
        },
        MyFunction: function () {
            var optionVal = this.data("MyExtension").testOption;
            console.log(optionVal);
        }
    };

})(jQuery);

$("body").MyExtension({testOption: "foobar!"}).MyExtension("MyFunction");
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this is just a simple scoping issue, I believe. You have the object options being passed into `init`, but it's local to that function. You need to put it on the object so that your other function, `MyFunction` has scope to it.

```
var methods = {
    init: function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            testOption: "test"
        };
        this.currentOptions = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
             // Code logic goes here
        }

    MyFunction: function () {
        var optionVal = this.currentOptions.testOption;
    }
};
```